# Personalize labels with CSS in Chart.js v2.4.0

Tags: html, css, chart.js, chart.js2

In previous versions of the library, I remember I could target an HTML element with CSS and style it.

```
.legend li {...}
```

Now it's all drawn in the Canvas and seems impossible to style the lables (I want to create checkbox like when you click on the label to show or hide the data of that specific label)
[image: Completed, Renewal, New and Failed are the labels I want to style]